# Getting a look-behind to look back as many characters as necessary?

Tags: c#, regex

I've this Regex:

```
(\[\[.*?\]\])(?<!".*?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tKRB6bXNvjHggOpe)

and this test data:

```
[[Hello]]
<tag Text="my [[Test]] is [[Test2]] for [[Test3]][[Test4]]">
```

How can I get that look-behind to ignore those that are preceded by a `"`?

It should match the `[[Hello]]` but not the remainder. However, it is of course matching them all.

Comment: Which language/implementation are you using?

Comment: @AmalMurali: my apologies, I've tagged it with `C#`. However, I'm testing it on Debuggex with the PCRE engine.

Comment: `(\[\[.*?\]\])(?<!".*?)` works fine and matches `[[Hello]]` in C#

Comment: You can test C# regex here: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression actually does the job for your specific input, I would write.. ( [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/98Vlpk) )

```
\[\[[^]]*\]\](?<!"[^"]*)
```

You may also consider using the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side.

And then you can refer to the capturing group to get your match result. ( [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/dyAmm1) )

```
"[^"]*"|(\[\[[^]]*\]\])
```

Comment: @AmalMurali It is a great used method for purposes like this where you can avoid lookarounds.

Comment: Indeed. I first came to know about it via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23589204/1438393) by [zx81](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1078583/zx81) :)

Answer (score 1):

### Discard technique

You can use the regex technique to discard what you dont want. It consists of having a pattern line:

```
discard1|other discard|more crap|(the content I want)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Notice that the content you want is the one on the **rightest side and within capturing groups**:

Said that, you can use this regex:

```
.*".*".*|.*?(\[\[.*?\]\]).*?
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW5iA0/3)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-9]   `[[Hello]]`
```

### Lookaround

On the other hand, if you want to use regex lookaround (lookbehind and lookahead) you can use this regex:

```
(?<!").*?(\[\[.*?\]\])(?!.*")
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW5iA0/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

But I like the discard technique, it's very clear and can save many headaches. You can learn many about it if you look for `zx81`, `anubhava` posts, they rock on regex.