# regular expression for password with few rules

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a function checkPassword function, which should check if the password parameter adheres to the following rules:

1. Must be longer than 6 characters
2. Allowed characters are lower or upper case Latin alphabet characters
   (a-z), numbers (0-9), and special characters +, $, #, \, / only
3. Must not have 3 or more consecutive numbers (e.g. "pass12p" is fine,
   but "pass125p" is not, because it contains "125")

checkPassword should print "true" to the console if the password parameter adheres to the said rules, and "false" if it does not.

Comment: What have you tried? And there are plenty of online checkers to test things out...http://www.regexr.com/ is one of my faves

Comment: You can use something like this: `([\w+$#/\\]){6,}` but doesn't fix point 3

Comment: @Fede: `\w` won't work, as it also matches underscores.

Comment: @theftprevention yes but that easily is solved to `([a-zA-Z\d$#/\\]){6,}` I just wanted to provide an option to OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex and get the content of the capturing group to check if your string is valid:

```
.*\d{3}.*|^([\w\+$#/\\]{6,})$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kV5lS7/1)**

Using `\w` allows `A-Za-z0-9_` if you don't want underscore on your regex you have to replace `\w` by `A-Za-z0-9`

For the following examples:

```
pass12p            --> Pass
pass125p           --> Won't pass
asdfasf12asdf34    --> Pass
asdfasf12345asdf34 --> Won't pass
```

Match information is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `pass12p`
MATCH 2
1.  `asdfasf12asdf34`
```

Comment: This is pretty clever, well done! I couldn't think of a way to do it with a single regex.

Comment: @theftprevention thank, glad you like it. That regex technique is very useful

Comment: @theftprevention I answered a question showing this more graphicaly, if you want you can take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190108/getting-a-look-behind-to-look-back-as-many-characters-as-necessary/25190225#25190225

Comment: -1 Your regex would validate e.g. `'abc27d££'` as you haven't anchored it with `^` and `$`.

Comment: @MikeM that caracter is not asked by OP. Don't downvote without reason

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use two separate regular expressions. First, make sure the password matches this first one, which checks for adherence to rules #1 and #2:

```
[A-Za-z0-9#$\/\\\+]{6,}
```

Then, make sure the password does *not* match this second regular expression, which checks for the presence of a sequence of 3 consecutive numbers anywhere in the password:

```
\d{3}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkPassword(str) {
  console.log( /^(?!.*\d{3})[+a-z\d$#\\/]{6,}$/i.test(str) );
}
```